# Gcloud Firestore emulators lost the data when restart

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I'm using `firestore emulator` for my `python` project.

I start it using this command.

`gcloud beta emulators firestore start --host-port=localhost:8080`

After saving docs and doing other stuff if I close the `firestore` and run it again it will lose
all data. I want `firestore` keep data until I clear data myself, is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for:

- `emulators:export` to export data from the emulator
- the `--import` flag to pass the exported data to the emulator on startup

Also see the Firestore documentation on [exporting and importing emulator data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#export_and_import_emulator_data).

Comment: not understand can you please provide example how can I run it in above command I'm using this `gcloud beta emulators firestore start --host-port=localhost:8080` to start `emulator`

Comment: The firebase documentation looked promising, but I got this error: `ERROR: (gcloud.beta.emulators.firestore.start) unrecognized arguments:
  --import=./db (did you mean '--host-port'?)` Are those flags only for firebase users and not gcloud?

Comment: Correct, this is applicable only to the Firebase emulators - so when you run the `firebase emulators:start` command.